# How to remove special character while fetching data

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

below is my query to fetch data ,my problem is that ,I am storing Address field as

`Address1%Address2%Address3`

now while fetching I want to fetch it as `Adress1 (newline) Adress2 (newline)Adress3`
How I can do this ?

for e.g. Dange%abc%Pune

as Dange

abc

Pune

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT FirstName,LastName,Address FROM Doctor_Master WHERE Type_of_Dr='" + typeofDr + "'", con))
```

Comment: For starters, this code is vulnerable to SQL injection.  You'll want to use parameterized queries instead of concatenating values directly into SQL code.  Beyond that, it's not clear what your issue is.  But it sounds like you're not storing data correctly.  Multiple values shouldn't go in a single field, they should be broken apart into multiple fields or multiple records.

Comment: I don't understand. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @SonerGönül In Address Column I am storing 3 text box values togather and saperating them with `%` character ,Now while fetching I want this 3 values to get displayed in report in 3 different lines ,so how can i do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pity that the `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` provider doesn't support the `Replace()` function like the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider does, otherwise it would be much easier for you.

I think you have to fetch the `Address` field normally and use a helper function to convert that `string` into the format you want, something like this:

```
public string GetBrokenLines(string address){
   return address.Replace("%","\r\n");
}
//instead of using the address directly, you just need to pass it into the GetBrokenLines
//method and get the expected result.
```

For filling `DataTable` using adapter, try this:

```
public static DataTable GetRefDrList(string typeofDr, bool display){
  DataTable refDrListTable = new DataTable();
  refDrListTable.RowChanged += Format;
  //....
  da.Fill(refDrListTable);
  //....
}
bool suppressFormat;
private void Format(object sender, DataRowChangedEventArgs e){  
  if(suppressFormat) return;     
  suppressFormat = true;
  e.Row["Address"] = e.Row["Address"].ToString().Replace("%","\r\n");       
  suppressFormat = false;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what `Replace` keyword will do here,its shoeing me this error `Undefined function 'Replace' in expression.`

Comment: @Durga it's a function which is supported by MS access engine. It is used to replace a string evaluated from an expression with some arguments passed in. You should google for it to learn more. To see the result, just fetch the query normally and try displaying the `Address` field in a `TextBox`, you will see multilines if there are more than 1 Address in the current record.

Comment: @Durga could you post the updated code? the query I posted should replace your query, the `...` is the remaining code which doesn't change.

Comment: `SELECT FirstName,LastName,Replace(Address,' % ',chr(10)&chr(13)) FROM Doctor_Master WHERE Type_of_Dr='" + typeofDr + "'"` this is my updated query

Comment: @Durga What version of Access are you using? Your string connection should use `ACE engine` instead of `Jet` engine, but the target machine should have at least Access 2007 installed. `Replace` is supported only in `ACE engine` (since Access 2007).

Comment: this is my connection string `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=sonorepo.mdb` I am using Access 2007,but saving .mdb as 2003

Comment: @Durga could you change it to `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;`? it can read both `mdb` and `accdb`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38694/discussion-between-durga-and-king-king)

Comment: @Durga as I suggested, you should re-design your database table. However I have a solution for your current approach. It should work for you, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the way you're storing the data. You could introduce a new table, Doctor_Master_Address. You could also add more columns to Doctor_Master if each doctor only has one address. That way you know there will definitely be a street name, province name, postal code, country etc.

If you still choose to use a value field, you could store the address as xml in that one field so it is easy to serialize the data. What if Address2 is omitted and then Address1%Address3 is parsed? If it's just delimited by '%' how do you know what Address3 represents?

If you still choose to use one field delimited by % check out [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx) for split string infromation.